# Should I inject DBContext into internal class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-5.0

I have an internal class that is used for mapping properties to models. I need to map a new property on a model to a separate dbcontext entity. Should I inject the dbcontext into the internal class too or is there a better way?

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository{
    public readonly MyDbContext _context;
    public MyRepository(MyDbContext dbContext){
        _context = dbContext;
    }

    public List<MyStuff> Get(MyReq req){
        var myStuff = _context.MyStuff.Include(r => r.OtherStuff).AsNoTracking();

        myStuff.Where(x => x.StuffId == req.StuffId).ToList();

        var myStuffList = new List<MyStuff>();

        foreach(var dm in myStuff){
            var m = MyMapper.MapMyStuff(dm);
            myStuffList.Add(m);         
        }
        return myStuffList;
    }
}

internal class MyMapper{
    public static MyStuff MapMyStuff(MyStuff dm){
        var myStuffModel = new MyStuff(){
            StuffId = dm.StuffId,
            StuffName = dm.StuffName, StuffColor = dm.StuffColor, ...ect.
            TheirStuff = // need to pull from _context.TheirStuff
        }
    }
}
```

This would probably work but I'm concerned that it may cause a performance issue because it would instantiate a new dbcontext every time. Is there a better way?

```
internal class MyMapper{
    public static MyStuff MapMyStuff(MyStuff dm){
        var _context = new MyDbContext();

        var myStuffModel = new MyStuff(){
            StuffId = dm.StuffId,
            StuffName = dm.StuffName, StuffColor = dm.StuffColor, ...ect.
            TheirStuff = _context.TheirStuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make _context static in MyMapper and pass it in the constructor..

Comment: You need to inject the mapper into the repository. If you want the mapper to use a separate instance you can configure that. `internal` isn't relevant to the question by the way